# Is it possible to define an operation (HTTP method) at server URL level using OpenAPI v3?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am new using OpenAPI v3. Let's suppose that I have defined my server URL as follows:

```
servers:
  - url: https://api.example.com
```

For some reason, I would like to define a method at server URL level. However, the documentation only shows how to define methods using a path, e.g.

```
paths:
  /users:
    get: ...
```

Thus, the full request URL for this method would be

`https://api.example.com/users`

Is it possible to define a method that uses the server URL as full request URL (without any path)? I would like to have a method that only uses the server URL:

`https://api.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Use `/` as the operation path:

```yaml
paths:
  /:
    get:
      ...
```